# how to build a marketplace e-commerce like ebay

Tags: php, html, web, e-commerce, marketplace

i am new to web programming

I know java, C++ quite well. but know i want to learn more about website
I already have basic about php,javascript,html,css,and mysql

So, I have a project, to build a e commerce website, like ebay
there are 2 stakeholders, which are seller and buyer

I have been doing some research about a open source e commerce like magento, and drupal

but it seems i have to pay for it, which i dont have money for

so I have been thinking about building one by myself

do you have any tips/tutorial/suggestions ?

it will be very useful for me

thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your question seems bit generic to me, let me answer this in a generic fashion.

If you want the quickest way to implement it, you've two of these main options to go with.

1. **Wordpress** - Install wordpress, and search for Ecommerce plugins, and you're done.
2. **Magento** - The second way is to opt for the dedicated platform for ecommerce, known as Magento - Its the popular one out in the market.

Below are the reference links:

[Wordpress](https://wordpress.org)

[WPEcommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-e-commerce/)

[Magento](https://www.magentocommerce.com/download)

Hope this information helps you to kick-start with the things.

Comment: sorry for my generic question, hehe